# How to get Grub2 to dual boot Windows 2000 and a Bart PE CD?

Tags: multi-boot, livecd, grub, windows-2000

- First, is this possible?
- Second, how can I install Grub2? Would it be possible to use an Ubuntu Live CD?
- Third, what Grub2 settings would be needed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, to install grub:

1) Boot to the Ubuntu LiveCD.

2) Open terminal (Under Applications —> Accessories).

3) In the window that opens, type the command `grub-install`.

4) Reboot the computer.

5) You should see grub pop up, move to the Operating System you want to boot to with the arrow keys and then press enter.

6) The operating system should boot. You're done!